# Android Facebook SDK Login Issue

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

I'm using Facebook Unity Plugin 4.3.4 and having issue with FB.Login()

Using logcat i have solved mismatched app id and key hashes now when i try to login it prompts a blank screen like it is going to authenticate but will then go right back to my application.

The delegate for the FB.Login() is not called until I press the button i assigned as the login button and it will produce the same result.

I do have the facebook app on the device and have tried removing it. When it is removed and i log in through the browser facebook says that the app is already authenticated so I'm assuming a portion of it must of worked for that to have happened

When i debug the result of the login I get no errors and {"is_logged_in":false,"user_id":"","access_token":""}

Right now im outta ideas.

This is the monobehaviour i have attached on the main scene of my application and the login button which is also on the main scene calls FacebookLogin()

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using JsonFx.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class FBObject : MonoBehaviour
{
public LGUI3DLabel connectFacebookLbl;

// Use this for initialization
void Awake ()
{
    FB.Init(OnFacebookInitComplete, OnUnityHidden);
}

void OnFacebookInitComplete()
{
    connectFacebookLbl.text = "AppID = " + FB.AppId;

    if(FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        OnLoggedIn();
    }
}

void OnUnityHidden(bool isGameShown)
{
    if(!isGameShown)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
    }
}

void OnLoggedIn()
{
    Debug.Log("Current User ID = " + FB.UserId);
    connectFacebookLbl.text = "Id = " + FB.UserId;
}

public void FacebookLogin()
{
    if(!FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        FB.Login("email,publish_actions", LoginCallback);
    }
    else
    {
        connectFacebookLbl.text = "Is Logged In";
        FB.API("/me?fields=id,first_name,friends.limit(100).fields(first_name,id)", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetUserInformation);
    }
}

void GetUserInformation(FBResult queryResult)
{
    if(queryResult.Error != null)
    {
        Debug.LogError(queryResult.Error);
        connectFacebookLbl.text = "There was an error\n"+queryResult.Error;
        return;
    }

    var reader = new JsonReader();
    var output = reader.Read<Dictionary<string, object>>(queryResult.Text);

    string userName = (string)output["first_name"];
    connectFacebookLbl.text = userName;
}

void LoginCallback(FBResult loginResult)
{
    connectFacebookLbl.text = "Trying to log in!";

    connectFacebookLbl.text = "Result = " + loginResult.Text;

    if(FB.IsLoggedIn)
    {
        connectFacebookLbl.text = "Wow we actually logged in!!!";
        OnLoggedIn();
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

}
}
```